# I'm trying to create an user defined header file and suffering from an error :(

Tags: c++, namespaces, function-definition, name-lookup

When I'm trying to compile my code, this message appears:

```
undefined reference to `N::my_class::do_something()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What can I do?

my_class.cpp

```cpp
#include "my_class.h" // header in local directory
#include <iostream> // header in standard library

using namespace N;
using namespace std;

void my_class::do_something()
{
    cout << "Doing something!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: The function should be in the `namespace N`, at least the linker tries to find `N::my_class::do_something`, not `my_class::do_something`.

Comment: [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 1):

This function definition

```
void my_class::do_something()
{
    cout << "Doing something!" << endl;
}
```

is placed in the global namespace. In fact it is equivalent to

```
void ::my_class::do_something()
{
    cout << "Doing something!" << endl;
}
```

But you need to define the function in the namespace N like for example

```
void N::my_class::do_something()
{
    cout << "Doing something!" << endl;
}
```